# How to match histogram of set of medical images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, image-segmentation

I have medical images of 100 patients (100 stacks of MRIs) and I want to do histogram matching on them using this [Matlab function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhistmatch.html)

```
B = imhistmatch(A,ref)
```

How can I choose `ref` patient MRI (as reference volume)? since the number of slices between patients varies, how can I perform histogram matching?

I am hoping someone here can recommend a solution that explains the process in a way that I can use or share any code. Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat because the intensity of images varies patient to patient.

Comment: @S.EB I dontk know much about MRI, but is not a different intensity actually information?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have to do some preprocessing and denoising that this intensity variation affects the whole process. So I have to match all patients intensity as a preprocessing step.

Comment: Then your `ref` will be whatever patient histogram works with your denoising right? So you can have a predefined `ref`

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks for your help. I was wondering should I consider a strategy for choosing a specific patient volume as a reference or not.

Comment: You said that you need to change the histograms because your preprocessing only works with specific ones. Well, there you have your criteria

Comment: @AnderBiguri Do you think taking an average of few reference images will work or not? thanks