# How to do histogram matching and calculate mean image for many stacks of images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix-multiplication, matlab-guide

I am hoping someone recommend a solution for me. I have 113 stacks of medical images, which is for 113 patients. The problem is intensity and contrast of each equivalent slice varies patient to patient. For example, `patient1` has 60 slices and `patient2` has also 60 slices. But the intensity and contrast of each equivalent slices are different between patients. I read in literature that histogram matching is applied, however, choosing a reference image is a bit tricky among 113 patients. I would like to take average of intensity of all pixels in a specific coordinate.

- Is my understanding correct to take average of all pixels and set it
  as reference image for histogram matching?
- how to do pixel-wise averaging for few stacks in `Matlab`?

Thanks

Comment: You can try to apply histogram equalisation [histeq(I)](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html) to all your images. You do not need to have an average image for this technique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match histogram of set of medical images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741287/how-to-match-histogram-of-set-of-medical-images)